# iframe with dynamically defined url is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, sapui5

I need to set a URL to iframe dynamically, but when I do so, the iframe is empty.

Here is the iframe's definition:

```js
<html:iframe id="myFrame" width="700px" height="500px"></html:iframe>
```

And here how I tried to set the URL:

```js
var sRedirectUrl = "http://google.com"; //dynamically defined url
var sIframeId = this.getView().byId(this.createId("myFrame")).getId();
$("#"+sIframeId).attr("src",sRedirectUrl);
```

[Here](http://jsbin.com/tosotajeki/edit?html,output) is jsbin example.
I also tried to do the following:

Definition:

```js
<IconTabFilter id="iframe_container">
</IconTabFilter>
```

Url set:

```js
var sRedirectUrl = "http://google.com"; //dynamically defined url
this.getView().byId(this.createId("iframe_container")).addContent(
    new sap.ui.core.HTML({
    content: "<iframe scr=\""+sRedirectUrl+"\" width='700px' height='700px'></iframe>"  
    })  
);
```

And it doesn't work also.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

UPDATE

Hard coding a generated link into iframe is working fine:

```js
<html:iframe id="myiframe" src="https://generated_link_to_some_site.com?uniqueId"></html:iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why iframe was empty is very simple - I tried to call the element before it was rendered.

It took me 3 days to realize that. Don't be like me.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing right, but Google does not allow iFrame, try with test.com in your jsbin instead and it will work : http://jsbin.com/vuqujoxupe/1/edit?html,output

Comment: google is just an example. I need to show in iframe a credit card payment form, which is dynamically created for each user by the credit card payments provider. And if I hard code the generated link into an iframe, it DOES work.

Comment: Weird, in my jsbin it works with your code and test.com url (so the url is loaded dynamically), maybe the page you are trying to load prevent iframe integration (for security reasons, prevent phishing...) ? But in this case it should'nt work if it's hard coded... I tried it on Chrome, it may be relevant.

Comment: thank you for your comments. In another app the iframe does work. Weird thing: the same code in another app makes `console.log($("#"+sIframeId));` return `[iframe#__xmlview0--myiframe, context: document, selector: "#__xmlview0--myiframe"]` element, while in the app I'm struggling with the same line returns `Q.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#__xmlview1--myiframe"}`

Comment: In the second case it looks like the iframe does not exist, maybe a typo on the id ?

Comment: No, there is no typo. `$("#"+sIframeId)` just can't find the element. How is that possible?